# Giving formula values with multi-select picklist

Tags: administration, formula, formula-field

I am trying to make a formula that will give values from a multi-select picklist and i want to know what is the fastest and cleanest way to do this?

Video_Monetizing_tool__c != "No" to give a value of 10. This means everything that is else in the picklist should be with value of 10 except No should be 0.

IF i do Case(Video_Monetizing_tool__c , "No","0" , "YES", "10", "Maybe", "10", "Often","10","null")
this will pass only the values that are set up but what if i select multiple values?

Please advise,
Darko

Comment: One of the many reasons that Multiselect picklists kind of suck. Do you want the values to be additive? Ie, does Yes + Maybe = 20? What happens if No and another value are selected?

Comment: Hi @ThomasTaylor.

The values should with combinations. YES + MAYBE=10 , YES + MAYBE+Often=10, YES + Often=10. ALl combinations give 10 except No gives 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
if(ISBLANK(Video_Monetizing_tool__c),NULL,IF(INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,'No'),0,10))
```

Comment: you are a genius ! This works !