# Multi-select picklist to give additional value

Tags: formula, picklist, formula-field

I am trying to edit one formula to have one additional value in the specific result.
Basically I've added additional value in the multi-select picklist (N/A), and I want that value to give the same result as the No value in the multiselect picklist.

I am working with the following code:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Video_Monetizing_tool__c),NULL,IF(INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"No"),0,10))
```

This is related to : [Giving formula values with multi-select picklist](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56857/giving-formula-values-with-multi-select-picklist)

Please advise,

Darko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regarding your formula here is a short explanation:

```
IF (ISBLANK(Video_Monetizing_tool__c), // if video monetizing tool != null
    NULL, // return null
    IF(INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"No"), // else return if Video Monetizing = no
    0, // 0
    10 // otherwise return 10
    )
)
```

In order to extend the existing functionality we have to exit the line `IF(INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"No"),`. The if argument has to be true in case Video_Monetizing_tool__c is contains to "No" or contains "N/A". Therefore we can use [the `OR()` operator.](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#OROR)

> [OR] evaluates if at least one of multiple values or expressions is true. Use this operator as an alternative to the logical function OR. - [SFDC Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#OROR)

The result looks like this:
`IF(OR(INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"No"), INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"N/A")),`

And this is the final result:

```
IF (ISBLANK(Video_Monetizing_tool__c),
    NULL,
    IF(OR(INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"No"), INCLUDES(Video_Monetizing_tool__c,"N/A")), 
    0,
    10
    )
)
```

Comment: thank you very much for explaining this in details it gives me really better perspective of how things are working.